# Polymer with Cordova

Tags: cordova, polymer, behavior, polymer-1.0

So I am in the process of building a web app using Polymer 1.0, I've done some work with 0.4-0.5 but nothing in between so I'm a bit lost. Before, I used to use an element called `<pvc-globals>`  to keep track of values and use them globally across elements but I see that has been replaced by Behaviors. The basic app works fine in mobile and desktop browser but when I compile it in Cordova it becomes erratic; Behavior stops working as the databound values don't show up and any link that click on just tells me that `File or directory could not be found file:///learn`. I'm using Page.js for routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. Apparently they got rid of `pvc-globals` and moved to using something called Behaviors as outlined in the migration guide. And for the file error, the routing file was being referenced incorrectly.